# span between vector and set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$v_1 = (1,2,3,4)$, $v_2 = (0,1,0,1)$, $v_3 = (1,1,2,2)$ and I am asked if the vector $u= (1,-1,5,3)$ belongs to $\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$

So I put this on the form of $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3 = u$ and got that $c_1 = 3$, $c_2 = -5$, $c_3 = -2$

This gives me $3v_1 -5v_2 -2v_3 = u$

$(3,6,9,12) + (0,-5,0,-5) + (-2,-2,-4,-4) = (1,-1,5,3)$

Since I just described vector $u$ as a linear combination of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ shouldn't this mean that the vector $u$ indeed is within the span? The key says its not in the span but I don't get how...

Comment: $u$ is in the span of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. I am assuming here that you are working in the Euclidean space.

Comment: Either you messed up somewhere solving the linear combination or the answer key is incorrect. i don't see any errors in the linear combination